# Excluding frames from handout when exporting to LaTeX Beamer

Tags: org-export, latex, beamer

I would like to exclude certain slides when I export my document as a handout using the corresponding option `#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [handout]`.

I know what I need to arrive at in LaTeX to achieve this:

```
\begin{frame}<handout:0>
...
\end{frame}
```

And I know that I can use the property `BEAMER_OPT` in Org Mode to specify frame arguments like `shrink` that will be passed on as optional frame options in square brackets to get, e.g., `\begin{frame}[shrink]`:

```
* Slide title
  :PROPERTIES:
  :BEAMER_OPT: shrink
  :END:
```

However, how can I use Org Mode to properly pass on the `<handout:0>` option in the required format in angle brackets?

Comment: Can you try with `:PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_ACT: <handout:0>
    :END:` ?

Comment: Yeah, it works! Great, thanks a lot! :)

How could I have found out? I couldn't find this option anywhere and maybe there are even more options I can use from org-mode that would be useful.

Comment: This was just a lucky guess. I found an example that used a similar syntax for blocks and thought it might be worth a try in case this also works for frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass overlay specifications to the frame using the following command:

```
:PROPERTIES:     
:BEAMER_ACT: <handout:0>     
:END:
```